# How to get this code to show movieclip correctly?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have the following code and it works fine, except I want it to play the `Explosion` movieclip in the library when an `EnemyShip` disappears but I only want it to play once and then disappear but not quite sure how to do it (I've tried a few things and it either makes the explosion animation loop and the ships don't disappear, which I believe is as a result of putting it inside the `kill` function, or I get other ArgumentErrors).

```
var speed:Number;
var shot = new ShotSound();
var explosion = new Explosion();

this.x = 800;
this.y = Math.random() * 275 + 75;
speed = Math.random()*5 + 9;
addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseShoot);

function enterFrame(e:Event)
{
   this.x -= speed;
   if(this.x < -100)
{
   removeEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
   stage.removeChild(this);
} 
}

function kill()
{
    stage.addChild(this);
    explosion.x = this.x;
    explosion.y = this.y;
    removeEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
stage.removeChild(this);
    shot.play();
}

function mouseShoot(event:MouseEvent)
{
    kill();
}
```

Thank for for any help I may receive.

Answer (score 2):

You need some script to fire when the Explosion reaches it's final frame.  A few ways you can do this:

1.
Dispatch an event on the last frame of your explosion animation.   eg.   `this.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));`  then listen for that event:

```
var explosion = new Explosion();
addChild(explosion);
explosion.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, removeExplosion);

function removeExplosion(e:Event):void {
    MovieClip(e.currentTarget).stop();
    MovieClip(e.currentTarget).removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, removeExplosion);
    removeChild(MovieClip(e.currentTarget));
}
```

2.
Have the explosion remove itself on the last frame of the animation. eg. `if(this.parent) parent.removeChild(this);`

3.
If you can't or don't want to modify the explosion timeline, use the undocumented AddFrameScript command:

```
var explosion = new Explosion();
addChild(explosion);
explosion.addFrameScript(explosion.totalFrames-1, function():void {
    explosion.stop();
    if(explosion.parent){
        explosion.parent.removeChild(explosion);
    }
});
```

---

Here is a tip with your setup:

add a function called removeMe (or similiar) to avoid redundant code (so you call this function on kill or when the ship goes out of bounds

```
function removeMe(e:Event = null):void {
    this.removeEventLIstener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrame);
    if(this.parent){
        this.parent.removeChild(this);
    }
    //any other cleanup that's required
}
```

Next, an updated kill function:

```
function kill(){
    var explosion = new Explosion();
    explosion.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, removeMe); //you need to dispatch this event on the last frame of the explosion timeline as shown below
    addChild(explosion); //add it to the ship so it stays with it as the ship moves

    //not sure what shot.play() does and if that belongs here.
}

//on the last frame of your explosion timeline:
stop();
dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
```

Comment: I tried using the `AddFrameScript` solution, but it gives the following error: `ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
 at MethodInfo-8()`

Comment: Updated the answer.   Forgot that your explosion wasn't the child of the posted code's context.

Comment: These three methods are much more efficient than using an ENTER_FRAME handler to check every single frame if the explosion is done.  The first method is the cleanest approach.

Comment: Hmm, I'm having some problems in that the explosion appears in the same place every time but I thought it would work so that the explosion animation will appear in the same location as where the ship is when it is clicked / 'shot'. Perhaps you'd be so kind as to take a look?

Comment: https://mega.co.nz/#!oh5RWbbC!UBZQoUl-UPzWPgLfkuP1GCtXSi8SsPGgsr1E7vIUats - That is my Game.fla. The code is in the timeline of the first frame of the `EnemyShip` movieclip (Edited the clip and added it in there)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you're never adding `explosion` to the display list.

Change

```
var explosion = new Explosion();
stage.addChild(this);
```

to

```
var explosion = new Explosion();
stage.addChild(explosion);
```

Once you've done that, you'll want to add a listener to `explosion` to find out when it has finished playing:

```
explosion.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onExplosionProgress);

function onExplosionProgress(e:Event):void 
{
    if(explosion.currentFrame == explosion.totalFrames)
    {
        // explosion has reached end of its timeline
        explosion.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onExplosionProgress);
        explosion.stop();
        stage.removeChild(explosion);
    }
}
```